# Lilypond: Is there a way to auto-crop the paper

Tags: crop, paper

In [Lilypond](http://lilypond.org) the paper size can be set to A4, A5, Letter and so forth. However I have only a short song, and I want to embed it lateron. Therefore the output from Lilypond must be cropped somehow.

Is there a possibility to let Lilypond itself do this? Some setting to the `\paper{}` block, perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- If you want only the first system, you can use the `-dpreview` command-line option.
- If you want multiple systems:

  `\include "lilypond-book-preamble.ly"`

  `\paper { oddFooterMarkup = ##f }`
- Have ImageMagick `convert` autocrop it with the `-trim` option, e.g. via a shell script.

Comment: Newbie question: What's a system in lilypond terms?

Comment: "System" is a musical term, not a lilypond term. The first system the first "line" of notes.

Answer (score 4):

I managed this with running:

```
lilypond -dbackend=eps -dresolution=600 --png FILE.ly
```

And a paper section within the FILE.ly like this:

```
\paper {
  indent = 0\mm
  line-width = 110\mm
  oddHeaderMarkup = ""
  evenHeaderMarkup = ""
  oddFooterMarkup = ""
  evenFooterMarkup = ""
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, with the great advantage that no third party package is necessary. I've created a croped-paper.ly definition and included it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is twelve years old now, but it still comes up on google.
Add this line to the top of the lilypond file...

```
#(ly:set-option 'crop #t)
```

It will produce another file called filename.cropped.pdf, or svg, or png, whatever you have it set to.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much! I re-visit this question about once a year, because I still haven’t found a good solution. But this is great! I can even use it trivially simple on the command line with the `-dcrop` flag.

Answer (score 0):

From the Lilypond [manual](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.9/Documentation/user/lilypond/Paper-size#Paper-size):

> Extra sizes may be added by editing
>   the definition for paper-alist in the
>   initialization file scm/paper.scm.

You can therefore add your own page sizes to the default ones.

Comment: Yes, I read that, too, but actually I have several songs, and doing trial-and-error with each to find the correct height and then editing paper.scm for each is a bit of a hassle. Auto-cropping to the minimum width/height would be much, much more useful.